How to fix Gitlab merge requests after merging sqashed commits
We have 2 branches: develop and master.
I made several merges develop to master with squash.
There were 75 original commits in develop,
and I merged 4 times into master.
I did this without using merge request in Gitlab,
just plain git.
And everything was ok.
Now however there's a problem, if I'm trying to
use merge request in Gitlab (for new changes),
Gitlab shows all the 75 old commits when comparing branches.
I'm not sure what to do. If I just proceed with merge request,
will it work ?
What will be the result ?
Anyway seeing 75 old commits is annoying,
I'd like to see only the new changes (anything that wasn't merged into master).
Any help will be appreciated

"What will be the result ?" Try it and see. Programmers try stuff.


I'd like to see only the new changes, anything that wasn't merged into master

Nothing was merged into master. Squash merge is not a merge! By doing squash merge you threw away the history. So Git now has no idea that there is any sense in which those commits are already merged. And the merge base was not advanced. So now this is what you get.

While it can be a little more troublesome to filter through, more history tends to be better than less, especially with so few commits (not say, thousands)
What you can do (though I don't recommend it unless you have an extreme case, such as undoing a lot of bad work or keeping your development process private while publishing publicly) is to craft the intermediate commit and then merge that
git diff $target..$new > ../full_diff.patch
git checkout $target
git apply ../full_diff.patch

Note future merges of your dev branch will still bring in the commits
Either live with this or make evil (I do not and cannot recommend doing this, as it just pushes the problem further upstream in your process)

create a new branch (development-development?!) to save the history
force-push your new design over the dev branch with your new history

